# How to update value in Firebase database from HashMap in java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I want to update **"isseen" from FALSE to TRUE** in Firebase database from given below method:

I'm having this HashMap inside sendMessage() metod:

```
Map<String, Object> messageTextBody = new HashMap<>();
messageTextBody.put("message", messageText);
messageTextBody.put("type", "text");
messageTextBody.put("from", messageSenderId);
messageTextBody.put("to", messageRecieverId);
messageTextBody.put("messageID", messagePushId);
messageTextBody.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
messageTextBody.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
messageTextBody.put("isseen", false);
messageTextBody.put("url", "");
```

and here is Firebase Database nodes:

[image]

and here is my function to update "isseen":

```
ValueEventListener seenListener;
 private void seenMessage(final String userID) {

 seenListener = rootRef.child(messageRecieverId).child(messageSenderId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

 for (DataSnapshot dss : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

 final Messages messages = dss.getValue(Messages.class);

 if (messages.getFrom().equals(messageSenderId) && messages.getTo().equals(userID)) {

 Map<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
 hashMap.put("isseen", true);
 dataSnapshot.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);

 }
 }

 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

 }
 });

 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
 super.onPause();

 reference.removeEventListener(seenListener);

 }
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Im not able to update isseen in firebase database from false to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While calling the 'updateChildren' method you have used the dataSnapshot object which is actually the parameter of onDataChange method. Instead you should use the object of DataSnapshot from your for-each loop, which is 'dss' in your case.